# Linq to MySql group by date

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I would like to get some data and group it by date only.
Next expressions is not working for me,EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(users.RegisterTime) inavlid type of member declaration.

```
  var result = (from users in userService.GetListSimple()
               .Where(d => d.RegisterTime >= new DateTime(2013, 01, 01) 
                        && d.RegisterTime <= new DateTime(2013, 01, 10,23,59,59))
                group users by new { EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(users.RegisterTime),
                users.partners.Name, users.partners.PartnerId } 
                into gr
                select new
                       {
                         gr.Key.Date,
                         gr.Key.Name,
                         gr.Key.PartnerId,
                         Amount = gr.Count()
                       }
               ).OrderBy(d => d.Date);
```

how to fix it ?

I am not sure that next method is optimal

```
var data = (from users in userService.GetListSimple()
          .Where(d => d.RegisterTime >= new DateTime(2013, 01, 01) 
                   && d.RegisterTime <= new DateTime(2013, 01, 10, 23, 59, 59))
                  select new
                        {
                            Date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(users.RegisterTime),
                            users.partners.Name,
                            users.partners.PartnerId
                        });



var result = (from du in data
              group du by new { du.Date, du.Name, du.PartnerId } 
              into gr
              select new
                     {
                      gr.Key.Date,
                      gr.Key.Name,
                      gr.Key.PartnerId,
                      Amount = gr.Count()
                     }
              ).OrderBy(d => d.Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to name your anonymous type properties

```
 var result = (from users in userService.GetListSimple()
                             .Where(d => d.RegisterTime >= new DateTime(2013, 01, 01) 
                                    && d.RegisterTime <= new DateTime(2013, 01, 10,23,59,59))
               group users by new {
                          Date = EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(users.RegisterTime), 
                          Name = users.partners.Name, 
                          PartnerId = users.partners.PartnerId } into gr
                              select new
                              {
                                  gr.Key.Date,
                                  gr.Key.Name,
                                  gr.Key.PartnerId,
                                  Ammount = gr.Count()
                              }
                ).OrderBy(d => d.Date);
```